# Angular POST to Spring Security JWT login always returns Unauthorized

Tags: spring, angular, authentication, jwt

I've set-up a stateless Spring Security application that uses JWT tokens for authentication. I've launched the application and tried to login over Postman with credentials I inserted into the database using a POST method (I've tried both form data and x-www-form-urlencoded) and it works successfully, it returns the JWT token and the expiration time. However, when I try to post to the same URL over Angular I always get Unauthorized; Bad credentials no matter if I use correct username-password combo.

I've tried POSTing 3 ways:

## 1

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  login(username: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(environment.api + '/auth/login', {
      'username': username,
      'password': password
    });
  }
}
```

## 2

```
login(username: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    let body = 'username=' + username + '&password=' + password;
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set('Content-Type', 'x-www-form-urlencoded');
    return this.http.post(environment.api + '/auth/login', body, {
      headers: headers
    });
  }
```

## 3

```
login(username: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    let body = new URLSearchParams();
    body.set('username', username);
    body.set('password', password);
    return this.http.post(environment.api + '/auth/login', body);
  }
```

But every single method keeps returning 401: Unauthorized, as if my username and password are always wrong (and I keep trying with correct ones that work on Postman). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: consider using CORS

Comment: @georgesvan CORS is already set-up, my requests follow through but it's not letting me authenticate...

Answer (score 1):

Here I share a piece of my Angulare login service that sends a login request to a Spring Login Controller running under localhost 8181. I hope this will help.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  sendCredential(username: string, password: string) {
    let url = "http://localhost:8181/token";
    let encodedCredentials = btoa(username+":"+password);
    let basicHeader = "Basic "+encodedCredentials;
    let headers = new Headers ({
        'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization' : basicHeader
    });

    return this.http.get(url, {headers: headers});

  }
```

Comment: There is a difference as I do not use Basic authentication, mine is stateless. Anyways, figured out the error, it was due to the Angular HttpClient service. Reverted to the Http service and it works great!

Comment: I use http as well

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, it was in the HttpClient itself not sending post data correctly for unknown reasons. Tried it with the Http service and it works as it should.

Comment: I am having similar issue. could you please share the code?